# What's the answer?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking

(Created Myself!)

### Layer 1:

(Solve for number, addition, 2 digits, *E12 series*)

At the trains station, there are **brown** stairs, **green** moss growing all around, and **black** railings. Further on, a sea of **brown** metal masks my view, with the aged **grey** clock ticking relentlessly on, and the **black** signs written "Do Not Lean On Railing". Time's almost up - my train, line **green blue black** is coming right now...

Hint:

> Be a hardware geek, you'll know from the resistance.

---

### Layer 2:

(The answer from layer one is needed to complete this puzzle).

Check previous answer:
(Rail Fence Cipher, Decode Twice, first key = tens digit, second key = ones digit):

> Yoe!eodmtctp1pu es l

Fill in $ symbols with numbers to execute the function needToRun()

```
'use strict';
var a = 53
var b = 36
var c = [5,7,3]
var d = c.join('')-0+$
var e = (d+'').split('')[$] 
var f = a + b + '' + c[1] 
var g = [c, a, $].flat().join('4') 
if([c[$],d].join('') - (((g[1]/2)/2+(g[9]-0))+''+g[0]+g[2]+g[1]) == 0){
    needToRun()
}

function needToRun(){
  console.log('Unlocked!')
}
```

Concatenate (not add) all $ numbers together into a big number, from first one to last one in order.

Then concatenate that with last question's answer (respectively).
It is six digits long.
Using that as key, unlock the next layer.

Hint:

> JS + Vigenere with 1234567890

---

### Layer 3:

(Use Previous Answer!!! Check Previous Hint, if needed)
Ifglb r86 x4 j9p6, r8bp5 J di pr1io 1kb 5 0n jec 5e9. Dl eh2q9qw. Cfq5jcdk o8omk8c jec O c6obp 9j o8b lkd75o 2, cfq5jcdk o8omk8c jec N c6obp 9j w, clt5d0dq r8ijkdf j90 P i9o6m 9p 5. I9jhqcik k1qf, 3fi38r5e6jb (dhfh iq9hk oe cgd0n8), occfq5 i9ik 99dgj, kc5k qfcdj fl 82g6, qf5e hkir9ggo qf5 jkbfr 82glbq m0o8 qf9j 89mf5i'n abw.

Pastebin for after  decryption:
https://pastebin.com/VjWAKcqF

Take first 10 digits of answer and continue to the last layer.

---

### Layer 4:

Check (Affine Cipher, First 8 digits slope (a), rest intercept(b)):

> Sgifjqbqr Sgddqsjw!

Ingredients Needed:
1 Number

Instructions:

1. Halve Number.
2. Hash first part (md5) and remove letters.
3. For the second part, take it's reciprocal and remove decimal points. Take first 5 digits again.
4. Absolute step 2.
5. Take first 5 digits of hash and add it to the other 5 digits.
6. Invert
7. ???? (Dog ate this step)
8. Serve.

You should have gotten: 137,354

Hint:

> (<<, rotate through, carry over)

What step is missing?

Comment: Is the first stage rot13(svir uhaqerq fvkgl) because rot13(qvssrerag pbyberq onaqf va erfvfgbef pbeerfcbaq gb qvssrerag qvtvgf bs erfvfgnapr)?

Comment: rot13(Lrf, ohg abg 416. )

Comment: Edited extra information because it was too hard.

Comment: With 3-bands it would add to 152, but that's neither 2 digits nor does the RF with  5 and then 2 work. Discarding the non-E12 result would make it 71, but 1 is impossible for RF

Comment: ... I guess my information sources about resistors were wrong.

Comment: and edited to maybe fix the problems.